# Rotating character Swift Playgrounds

Tags: ios, ipad, swift-playground

I do not know what I did wrong in this code:

```
func findDegree() -> Double {
    let xValue = directionstick.center.x - 35
    let yValue = directionstick.center.y + 20
    let newX = xValue*xValue
    let newY = yValue*yValue
    let hypo = (newX+newY).squareRoot()
    return (xValue/hypo)

}
```

This code is for finding the amount of rotation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! Your question is a little unclear. Can you provide more context and preferrably more code? Rotation of what? And in relation to what? What is `directionstick`? A complete example with reproducible results would be best.

Comment: Really it should be a code that could rotate anything. For example rect.rotate(FindDegree())

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
func findDegree() -> Double {
    let xValue = directionstick.center.x - 35
    let yValue = directionstick.center.y + 20
    let angle = atan2(xValue, yValue)
    Return angle
}
```